# How to prevent flexbox row from MOVING UP when other items are wrapped

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive-design, nav

im trying to make navbar using flexbox for learning purposes, and i want to hide all elements that are being wrapped to the second row. I achievied that by `overflow: hidden` and `flex-wrap: wrap`

But the main problem now, is that when items are being moved to new row, the first one is moving higher to allow centering them both in container.

[image]

I want to keep only my first row centered, and second one to go with a flow. (I mean i will use gap or margin-top to move it away from my first row, and even parent container, but the drawing is simplified.)

I achieved what i drawed with:

```
position: relative;
left:0;
top:50%;
transform: translateY(-25%);
```

but it doesnt seem to be responsive and ideal solution, because what if the third row will appear. I wonder if there is a better way to do it without media queries.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have a `align-content: center` rule on the flexbox;
if you set it to `align-content: start` it should act like how you've described.

```css
.example {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: start;
  /*padding vertical alignment */
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* no actual height, will grow to largest content*/
  /*max-height for cut off */
  max-height: 70px;
  /* additional styles */
  border: 5px solid #333;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.large {
  max-width: 400px;
}

.small {
  max-width: 200px;
}



.item {
  border: 5px solid #a349a4;
  border-radius: 4px;
  min-height: 40px;
  min-width: 150px;
  margin: 2px 20px;
  /* use align-self: start to stop stretching */
  align-self: auto;
}

.two {
  min-height: 50px;
}

.solution-2 .item{
  margin: auto 20px;
}
```

```html
solution 1:  align-content: start, children will stretch to equal size
<div class="solution-1">
  <div class="example large">
    <div class="item one"></div>
    <div class="item two"></div>
  </div>


  <div class="example small">
    <div class="item one"></div>
    <div class="item two"></div>
  </div>

</div>


solution 2:  align-content: start, item with auto margin, will self-verrtical center.
<div class="solution-2">
  <div class="example large">
    <div class="item one"></div>
    <div class="item two"></div>
  </div>


  <div class="example small">
    <div class="item one"></div>
    <div class="item two"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```